# regex to know if some strings are joined by another string

Tags: python, regex

I am making a mini-parser of sql to estimate the maximum length of the value that an operation or a function will return. Ex: round (column, 2). For that, I am using regular expressions. For the example I gave, I got the regular expression `round\((\w+)(,\s*(\d+))?\)`.

However, I came across these cases

`column1||column2||column3||... columnn`
`concat(column1, column2, ... columnn)`

I tried for the first case (although I knew it wouldn't work), with regex like:

`(\w+\|\|\w+)+`
`(\w+\|\|\w+\|\|)|(\|\|\w+\|\|\w+)`

What regex do you propose to match the above cases? Or rather a more general question: How could I know if n strings are joined with a specific string?

Comment: Don't use a regex to parse sql.  Or any other non-regular language.  At least, don't do it if you are going to run this on sql you haven't generated yourself...

Comment: Don't worry, it's for a personal module that I'm making and I'm going to create the regex for specific cases. But thanks anyway for the advice! I will keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: Obligatory link to this [tangentially related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/15452601) question

Comment: What strange answers, next to what the google translator shows I did not understand almost anything. But it is true that it can have certain flaws, regex is not perfect. And there may be sql injections. But I will make sure that the only one who enters that data will be me!

Comment: It's a very funny but somewhat over used answer.  there's even a [meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252385/why-do-parsing-html-with-regex-questions-come-up-so-often) about it.  But the takeway is: don't expect to build a *robust* parser  with regexs: use a real parser instead.  Sometimes regexs are fine however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What regex do you propose to match the above cases?

To match `column1||column2||column3||... column10` use `(column\d||)+` regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match("(column\d(\|\|)?)+","column1||column2||column3||column4")
>>> m.group(0)
'column1||column2||column3||column4'
```

Use similar regex for the second case.

Comment: Wow, it worked! I don't know how it didn't occur to me ...
I created the regex (\ w + (\ | \ |)?) + From your idea and I managed to create the other one as you proposed! Thanks, I don't really know how I could be so stupid!